# Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'/`push'

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am running a 64 bit kernel on a 64 bit processor. I have to build kernel 2.4.32 in order to install the kernel module of a specific software. But `make bzImage` shows these error:

```
bus.c: Assembler messages:
bus.c:647: Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'
bus.c:649: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
bus.c:685: Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'
bus.c:689: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
```

The error is from bus.c file from functions `spin_lock_irqsave` and `spin_unlock_irqrestore` with these definitions:

```
#define spin_lock_irqsave(lock, flags)      do { local_irq_save(flags);       spin_lock(lock); } while (0)
#define spin_unlock_irqrestore(lock, flags) do { spin_unlock(lock);  local_irq_restore(flags); } while (0)
```

The problem is from functions `local_irq_save` and `local_irq_restore`:

```
#define local_irq_save(x)   do { warn_if_not_ulong(x); __asm__ __volatile__("# local_irq_save \n\t pushfq ; popq %0 ; cli":"=g" (x): /* no input */ :"memory"); } while (0)

#define local_irq_restore(x)    __asm__ __volatile__("# local_irq_restore \n\t pushq %0 ; popfq": /* no output */ :"g" (x):"memory")
```

please help me how can I fix the problem!

Comment: So what is the assembly code that generates these errors?  Use `gcc -O2 -S ... foo.c` to find out (and include that in the question).  Maybe also include what gcc version you're using.  (`as` version shouldn't matter; I assume you're actually getting invalid asm generated).

Comment: `popq` requires 64bit, but perhaps you are building for 32bit?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I thought of that, too, but the Linux kernel build system should get this right.  2.4.31 was released in 2005, so it did come after x86-64.  The [timestamps on 2.4.32 and later](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/) may be bogus, since they all show as May 2013, which is [after Linux 2.4 was abandoned (April 2012)](http://www.internetnews.com/blog/skerner/linux-2.4-hits-the-end-of-the-line.html).  Anyway, maybe the 3-rd party kernel module is causing the problem.  Hmm, I thought the OP said they were building a 64-bit kernel, but we only know the host is 64-bit.

Comment: Something is wrong with how you configured your kernel build or with your compiler installation. There's no way of knowing what the exact problem is, but its likely something to do a mixup between 32-bit and 64-bit as David Wohlferd suggests. The only way I can see this error being generated is if `long` is 32-bits and you're assembling in 64-bit mode. So GCC appears to be generating 32-bit code but the assembler is treating it as 64-bit code.

Comment: As an experiment, you could remove the `q` from the push/pop (or change it to a lower case `L`).  I know that longs are only 32bits on Windows (even in 64bit mode), but I don't see how that can apply here.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd neither `pushl` nor 'push does solve the problem. `pushl` leads to error `Invalid instruction suffix for push` because of using 64 bit register `rax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Im amateur in kernel compiling.. How can I use `gcc -02 -S foo.c` to find out which code generates the error among lots of .c file in several directories of a kernel? I use `gcc version 5.3.1`

Comment: That helps narrow things down.  If you look at `gcc -v`, what does it show for Target?  As for knowing which file produces the error, your original post refers to bus.c.  In fact, can't you see the actual build command being executed by 'make' when it encounters the error?  Your system could have more than one gcc.  The command line would make it clear which one you are actually using. I'm guessing we're going to find a 64bit compiler that uses 32bit longs.

Comment: What's the full `gcc` command line printed by `make` that generates this error message?  That will tell us everything we need to know.  Also, you can add a `-S` to it to get the asm instead of a `.o`

Comment: @DavidWohlferd The field of Target in `gcc -v` is `Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`. And the actual build command is `gcc -D__KERNEL__ -I/usr/src/linux-2.4.32/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -pipe -fno-reorder-blocks -finline-limit=2000 -fno-strength-reduce -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unit-at-a-time -march=k8  -Os  -DACPI_DEBUG_OUTPUT -nostdinc -iwithprefix include -DKBUILD_BASENAME=bus  -c -o bus.o bus.c`

Comment: Huh.  Not the target I was expecting at all.  To produce the asm: `gcc -D__KERNEL__ -I/usr/src/linux-2.4.32/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -pipe -fno-reorder-blocks -finline-limit=2000 -fno-strength-reduce -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unit-at-a-time -march=k8 -Os -DACPI_DEBUG_OUTPUT -nostdinc -iwithprefix include -DKBUILD_BASENAME=bus -S -o bus.s bus.c`.  You'll need to be in the dir that contains bus.c.  Look for `# local_irq_` in bus.s.

Comment: @PeterCordes I changed the Makefile to add -S to CFLAGS but it makes an error `ld:sched.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script`

Comment: @N.S.: yes, of course that happens, because you didn't remove the `-o sched.o`, and it still tries to link.  Look in `sched.o` and you'll find the compiler's asm output instead of an object file.  What I normally do is copy/paste the gcc command line and then modify it.  (But you have to figure the subdirectory the build scripts were running gcc from.)

Comment: The bus.s file includes these lines for 4 usage of `local_irq_`:: `# local_irq_save 
  pushfq ; popq %ebp ; cli`     `# local_irq_restore 
  pushq %ebp ; popfq`      `# local_irq_save 
  pushfq ; popq %r12d ; cli`      `# local_irq_restore 
  pushq %r12d ; popfq`